Scrapy - download images to a freshly created folder that has ID of just saved record in DB
I found similar questions on SO, but I was not able to piece it together to make it work.
I am scraping data from a website where are also images. My items.py looks` like this:
import scrapy

class BookPipeline(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    ...
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

In my_spider.py is the following:
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
     ...
     custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'project.pipelines.BookPipeline': 400,
            'project.pipelines.CustomImageNamePipeline': 1
        },
        'IMAGES_STORE': 'book_images'
    }
     ...

When I run my spider, it saves the images to the book_images folder, that's good.
What I would like to achieve, though, is to save the images to book_images/ID-OF-JUST-SAVED-BOOK-IN-DATABASE, so the files would be saved in this structure:

book_images/323/some-hash-name.jpg
book_images/323/another-hash-name.jpg
book_images/323/different-hash-name.jpg
book_images/5211/hash-name.jpg

I saw some snippets of code in custom pipelines, but I was unfortunately not able to make it work.
Also, I what I don't know yet - are the images downloaded by Scrapy first and then the record is created in the database, or the other way around?
EDIT: I tried something like this:
pipeline.py
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
import os

class BookPipeline:
  ...

class CustomImageNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return [scrapy.Request(x, meta={'image_dir': item["uni_id"]}) 
                for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        url = request.url
        media_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()
        media_ext = os.path.splitext(url)[1]

        return f'{request.meta["image_dir"]}/%s%s' % (media_guid, media_ext)

But no file gets saved, and there's no error message.  Also, in the console is no mention of any downloaded file.

You need to create a pipeline and add the path in the method file_path to your IMAGES_STORE dir, and then return the new path.

To achieve that, you will need to create two pipelines; one for saving data to the database and getting the id of the inserted record and the other one will be the images pipeline. Order of execution depends on their priority setting in the ITEM_PIPELINES definition. In this case, you need the DB pipeline to have a smaller number than the images pipeline i.e.
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    "project.pipelines.SQLiteDBPipeline": 300,
    "project.pipelines.CustomImageNamePipeline": 400,
}

In the database pipeline's process_item method save the item to the database and add the id returned to the item definition. Example using sqlite as below:
import sqlite3

class SQLiteDBPipeline:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("sqlite.db")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        # your code to insert into database goes here
        cur.execute("SQL QUERY HERE")
        id = cur.lastrowid
        item["id"] = id
        cur.close()
        return item

In your images pipeline, use the id value to create the file path required e.g.
import hashlib
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class CustomImageNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        # create a hash using the image url
        image_url_hash = hashlib.shake_256(request.url.encode()).hexdigest(16)
        return f"{item['id']}/{image_url_hash}.jpg"

NOTE: Include id as a field in your item definition for the above code to work.
import scrapy

class BookItem(scrapy.Item):
    id = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    ...
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

